# How to fix OpenSSL incorrect data transferring?

Tags: c++, openssl

I need to transfer serialized data using OpenSSL. My code works but for some cases transferred data has some differences.

This is serialized data http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02935614701824936895

```
int sslWrite(SSL *ssl, const void *buf, int num)
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 0x10000;

    const int INT_SIZE = sizeof(int);
    const int numv = INT_SIZE + num;

    if (numv > MAX_SIZE) {
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<char> bufv(numv);

    memcpy(&bufv[0], &numv, INT_SIZE);
    if (num != 0) {
        memcpy(&bufv[INT_SIZE], buf, num);
    }

    int n = 0;
    while (n < num) {
        int w = SSL_write(ssl, &bufv[0], numv - n);
        if (w < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        n += w;
    }

    return n;
}

int sslRead(SSL *ssl, void *buf, int num)
{
    const int INT_SIZE = sizeof(int);
    const int BUF_SIZE = 0x10000;
    char bufv[BUF_SIZE];

    int m = SSL_read(ssl, (char *)bufv, num);

    if (m < 0) {
        return m;
    }

    const int n = *(int *)(bufv);

    if (n > BUF_SIZE - INT_SIZE) {
        return -1;
    }

    while (m < n) {
        int k = SSL_read(ssl, (char *)bufv + m, num - m);
        if (k < 0) {
            return k;
        }
        m += k;
    }

    memcpy(buf, &bufv[INT_SIZE], n - INT_SIZE);
    return n - INT_SIZE;
}
```

-

```
// Server
#include <fstream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>

int OpenListener(int port)
{
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        perror("can't bind port");
        abort();
    }
    if (listen(sd, 10) != 0) {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = SSLv2_server_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

int main()
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitServerCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "sert.crt", "sert.key");
    server = OpenListener(3456);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);

    int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

    SSL *ssl;
    printf("Connection: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

    if (SSL_accept(ssl) == -1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    else {
        std::ifstream fin("data", std::ios::binary);
         std::string data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        fin.close();

        sslWrite(ssl, &data[0], (int)data.size());

        const int BUF_SIZE = 0x10000;
        std::string data1;
        data1.resize(BUF_SIZE);
        int n = sslRead(ssl, &data1[0], BUF_SIZE);
        data1.resize(n);

        /////////////////////////////////////////
        bool b = (data == data1); // b - FALSE!!!
        /////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    SSL_free(ssl);
    closesocket(client);
}
```

-

```
// Client
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>

SSL_CTX *InitCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = SSLv2_client_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

int OpenConnection(const char *hostName, int port)
{
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostName)) == NULL) {
        perror(hostName);
        abort();
    }
    int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        closesocket(sd);
        perror(hostName);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string &hostName = "localhost";
    const int port = 3456;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    SSL_library_init();

    SSL_CTX *ctx = InitCTX();
    int server = OpenConnection(hostName.c_str(), port);
    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == -1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    else {
        const int BUF_SIZE = 0x10000;
        std::string data;
        data.resize(BUF_SIZE);
        int n = sslRead(ssl, &data[0], BUF_SIZE);
        data.resize(n);

        sslWrite(ssl, &data[0], (int)data.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must deal with partial writes and partial reads.

For `SSL_write()` you need to check the return value to make sure your data was completely written. If your data was only partially written you need to call `SSL_write()` again for the remaining data. Repeat until all your data is written.

For `SSL_read()` you need to keep reading until you get a zero return value, then check for a clean shutdown. While doing this you need to append to your buffer and build it up as you receive data.

Update:

@dascandy in comments is correct.

You need to know when to stop reading as well as dealing with partial reads. Closing the connection alone will not work in your case because when you close the connection with SSL you lose the ability to send the reply on the same connection. SSL does not have "half open" connections like TCP.

A reasonable approach is to prefix each message with a byte count when sending, and when receiving first read the byte count (using whatever encoding is convenient -- fixed length, text with delimiter, whatever) and then read exactly that number of bytes into your buffer.

Comment: I am attempting to do as you said. But SSL_read doesn't get zero return value. Instead of this it tries to get next data as I understand. Code edited.

Comment: @Ufx You need a loop around both `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` to make sure you complete the read and the write operations. `SSL_read` will return the data that is available at the time of the call; this is not guaranteed to be all of the data written by the other end.

Comment: Can you correct my `sslRead` and `sslWrite`? I don't know how to break a cycle in `sslRead`. `(m == 0)` does not work.

Comment: @Ufx It *does* work: it just doesn't do what you think it does. It returns zero when the peer has disconnected. You are using it as an end of message indicator. It isn't, and there are no messages in TCP. Your code would be wrong even if you weren't using SSL at all.

Comment: @Ufx by having some form of protocol on top of TCP for figuring out when your packets end, or by closing the connection.

Comment: @dascandy could you correct my `sslRead` function please?

Comment: @Ufx "Correcting" your `sslRead` function isn't enough -- You need to also send information on when to stop reading. See the updated answer above.

Comment: @janm Do you mean the first byte must be equalled data size?

Comment: @Ufx In principle yes, but one byte will not be enough if you are sending more than 255 bytes in your message. The number of bytes depends on how big your messages will be -- Select an appropriate size for your messages. If you want to be more flexible you can implement a variable length size, for example a sequence of ASCII digits with a terminator.

Comment: Why does it happen? Why not all data received by one call?

Comment: @Ufx SSL is a streaming protocol providing a reliable byte stream service. If you want to have a concept of "all the data in a message" you need to implement that on top of the reliable byte stream. Consider a sender that sits in a loop and calls SSL_write forever. How would the receiver get all the data in one call?

Comment: @janm I edited sslWrite and sslRead. But they still work incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I suggest you get it working without SSL first, then you'll see for yourself what's wrong. It would have been helpful if you had investigated the difference between `data` and `data1`, rather than just setting a boolean. Try that, in plain text.

Comment: @EJP I don't very well understand you. What does mean without SSL? `data.size()` equals `data1.size()`. But `data` doesn't equal `data1`. Could you correct my `sslWrite` and `sslRead` functions please?

Comment: If you don't understand what 'without SSL' means, or 'investigate the difference', I doubt that you will understand anything else I could say. Let's try this, though: 'doesn't equal `data1`' *how*?

Comment: Can somebody just correct my `sslWrite` and `sslRead` functions please? Didn't anyone have such a problem?

Comment: @Ufx This isn't a service where people write code for you. There are many problems with the sslRead and sslWrite functions in your current question -- The buffer handling in sslWrite is wrong, just write from the size variable and directly from the buffer. The way you are using a vector is incorrect and will lead to program failure. Deal with partial writes in both of these cases. In sslRead you need to deal with partial reads when reading the size. The problems you are having here have nothing to do with SSL, they have to do with the way your program is written.

Comment: I found the mistake. `int k = SSL_read(ssl, (char *)bufv + n, num - m);` There is need `+m` instead of `+n`. Now result is correct. Are my `sslRead` and `sslWrite` functions look correct? Do I have to make some else corrections?

Comment: @Ufx Glad you got it working. Your sslRead function should deal with partial reads on the length and should check for buffer overflows if the received length value is greater than the size of the buffer. Both functions should deal with errors on the read/write operation; the current implementations will get stuck if things break.

Comment: @Ufx Getting there! You need to check for failure and partial read on the first call to SSL_read in sslRead.

Comment: @janm I edited `sslRead`. Are `sslWrite` and `sslRead` correct now?